# How to return powershell script status to python

Tags: python, powershell

As part of a process at work we run a power shell script that connects to active directory. Trying to automate the process I don't want to change any of this code but would like to return a warning/status

powershell pseudo code:

```
some code
if user == terminated:
    Write-Warning 'terminated'
else:
    a thing
```

python pseudo code:

```
some-things
for rows in users:
    status = run above powershell command
    if status == 'terminated':
       go delete user
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to capture what was written using `Write-Warning`? You could capture the output from the script and look for it, but there are better ways to communicate a failure to run correctly from a PowerShell script to another process (like a Python script calling it)

Comment: I was going to just use the code that's there but I could add functionality to whats there without causing a fuss (said I was going to automate and boss threw a hissy fit because of this bit)

Comment: Aside from pseudo-code, have you tried anything? The Python `subprocess` module allows you to obtain return codes, access to both the standard out and error text output streams, and of course you could also communicate by way of a file by writing output to a file from the script. Something like `subprocess.Popen` gets you everything but the kitchen sink in this respect.

Comment: I had no idea this existed thank you for the suggestion!!!